# what does axis = -1 mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
x= array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]]
tf.reduce_sum(x, axis = -1)
```

If `axis = 0` implies rows and `axis = 1` indicates columns, what does `axis = -1` mean?

Answer (score 1):

It specifies the last axis (first from the end).
Negative indexes are a concept that is used quite often in Python and other languages as well, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(a[-1]) # 4
print(a[-2]) # 3
```

Here's a relevant [article](https://www.codingem.com/python-indexing-from-end/) if you want to look more into it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33042552)

Comment: I agree, that's why I never post link-only answers. That said, you don't think that the post (without the link) covers the question? I only gave the link as supplementary material.